# How does the UAE manage the Western cultural influence?

Tags: united-arab-emirates

- [UAE Escape With Venezuelan Girlfriend](https://youtu.be/TNtfKTZiMDA?t=367)

This video shows that a South African YouTuber is in the UAE with his Venezuelan girlfriend, supposedly visiting, purportedly, a water park. I see a lot of locals in the background; children too.

Walking in public wearing bikinis and panties is an offensive practice in the Muslim culture.

Given that UAE is a Arab Muslim country, how do they perceive the Western cultural influence on the locals?

Are they concerned that foreigners are walking around in front of their childen half-naked?

If not, why?

Comment: Perhaps, like most countries, they tolerate unusual behavior by foreigners because they don't know any better or because "their customs are not our own"? For instance, a foreigner who goes to Japan and tries to order food by using humble verbs for the server and honorific verbs for themself, and calls them "omae" on top of that, they are unlikely to get more than a strange look, even though this would plausibly be taken as a serious and bizarre insult if a Japanese person did it.

Comment: @Obie2.0, This argument doesn't apply as 88% of UAE's are foreigners. Native Emireti's are minorities.

Comment: Seems to me that that would actually strengthen the argument. A country where most of the people are foreigners might well be more accepting of the cultural differences of its residents and visitors, because it already has so many of those differences within it.

Comment: Maybe a behaviour that is not tolerated on the high street is tolerated in water parks.

Answer (score 9):

The video is basically an advert, both for the author's own business partners and for the United Arab Emirates.

The UAE, and especially Dubai, welcome western foreigners both as tourists and to settle there. Ca. [500,000 of the 9 million inhabitants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expatriates_in_the_United_Arab_Emirates) are from western countries. Especially influencers like the author of the video are welcome. A business website [boasts](https://www.arabianbusiness.com/industries/media/dubai-is-the-new-l-a-influencers-flock-to-uae-to-max-social-media-followers)

> The UAE is now home to over 25,000 influencers with between 1,000 and 10 million followers, according to a recent [report](https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/united-arab-emirates#:%7E:text=We%27re%20currently%20tracking%20a,between%201%2C000%20and%2010m%20followers).

Another promotor sees Dubai at rank 8 of [the cities with the most instagram mega influencers](https://hypeauditor.com/blog/most-influential-cities-in-the-world-the-top-ten-cities-with-the-most-instagram-mega-influencers/) worldwide.

Influencers wanting to settle in and post from the UAE have to [aquire a media licence](https://www.meydanfz.ae/media-regulatory-offices-in-uae/) for a fee. Part of the licence is the commitment to only publish positive opinions about the UAE and its government. While I was not able to find the text of the licence itself, the relevant [Federal Law No. 15 of 1980 Governing Publications and Publishing](https://www.ilo.org/dyn/natlex/docs/WEBTEXT/62110/65257/E80ARE01.htm), especially Chapter 7 on prohibited material gives a picture:

> Section 70
> The person of the President of the Republic or the rulers of the Emirates may not be criticized.
>
> Section 71
> Any material which includes an incitement to, and is harmful to Islam, or the system of Government in the country, or harms the country's interests or the basic systems on which the society is founded shall be prohibited.
>
> Section 77
> Material which causes an injustice to Arabs or constitutes a misrepresentation of Arab civilization or heritage may not be published.
>
> Section 84
> Slandering the work of a public official, a person having a public prosecution function, or a person who is in charge of a public service shall not be allowed. A writer shall be exempted from responsibility if he/she proves he/she is well intentioned...

In short, the deal works as follows: Promote the public image of our country, and you can run your advertising business from here and profit from our advantageous tax legislation.

*I am mostly paraphrasing the critique German comedian Jan Böhmermann passed in his late night TV show in [February 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMzLpuBD-1M). I would welcome anyone who knows of sources of a more serious nature, both confirming and falsifying his claims, although most times his research turns out to be relatively sound.*

In order to not alienate the westerners, [rules for moral behaviour](https://www.emirates247.com/news/emirates/uae-laws-you-must-know-to-stay-out-of-trouble-2012-02-28-1.445519) have some obvious loopholes (The quote is ten years old and maybe outdated, as the video in question would probably cross the line):

> Strictly speaking, sharing a private space with a member of the opposite sex when not related by family ties or marriage is forbidden. Private space would be a house, room, hotel room and even car.
>
> However, certain behavior is tolerated. Hotel reservations are easily made for unmarried couples wanting to share a room and there are many cases of single men and women sharing a villa, apartment and even a room. Any punishment depends on the situation.
>
> In public places, guidelines say shorts and skirts need to be of appropriate length not to indecently expose parts of the body, be transparent, or display obscene or offensive pictures and slogans. On beaches rules are more lenient; swimwear is accepted but should be appropriate. Top-less sunbathing or the wearing of a thong is not allowed.